# FirebaseUI -Android Email Link Sign In not working

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I am Configuring Email Link Sign In using Firebase UI. where am i am going wrong?

I have enabled the  email link sign in the Firebase Console. Additionally, i  have also enabled enabled Firebase Dynamic Links as per the documentation hear: 
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md

```
ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings
    .newBuilder()
    .setAndroidPackageName("com.appfirebase", /*installIfNotAvailable*/false, /*minimumVersion*/null)
    .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
    .setUrl("https://appfirebase.com") // This URL needs to be whitelisted
    .build();

if (AuthUI.canHandleIntent(getIntent())) {
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        return;
    }

    String link = getIntent().getExtras().getString(ExtraConstants.EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN);
    if (link != null) {
        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                            .setEmailLink(link)
                                            .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
                                                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().enableEmailLinkSignIn()
                                                            .setActionCodeSettings(actionCodeSettings).build())).build(),RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
}
```

I expect the above code to  send a login email to the email address which on click it verifies the email and logs in the user but it disables the log in.Such that Firebase UI- Android signing  screen disappears. I am i missing something on documentation?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, https://appfirebase.com isn't a valid URL. After you update the URL to something valid, be sure to whitelist it in your Dynamic Link.